# Google Structured Query Parameters Not Working For List Feed

Tags: coldfusion, google-sheets-api

Using [this documentation for reference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data) as well as url escaping certain characters, I have the following spreadsheet being read via Spreadsheet API and I'm trying to fetch specific rows only: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E5ROfSQAuQvqx7o61Au9eEd-6B7W35gfj3g7C6VhpGY/

If I try to filter by badgenumber I get zero results back

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1E5ROfSQAuQvqx7o61Au9eEd-6B7W35gfj3g7C6VhpGY/od6/public/values?sq=badgenumber%3D%2212345%22

`<openSearch:totalResults>0</openSearch:totalResults>`

Comment: Do the badge numbers include the word 'badgenumber'?

Comment: Badgenumber is the column, and I'm trying to filter rows by the value I pass in for badgenumber. The documentation for querystring parameters are unusual for GDocs which is why you see two sets of equal signs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sq=badgenumber="12345"

Your current parameter has double quotes. Try removing them. This query string worked for me:

```
?sq=badgenumber%3D12345
```

It also worked with the first and last name columns, which are clearly strings. So it seems like quotes are not required:

```
?sq=firstname%3DDan
?sq=lastname%3DKusanago
```

Comment: A thousand thank you's! I read so many different articles about what to escape and not escape that it one _had_ to be right.

Comment: Yeah, reading over reams of documentation makes you bleary eyed after a while ;-) Glad I could help.

Comment: Brief follow-up, would you know if fuzzy searches are capable? I tried escaping the percent sign and it gave me invalid parameter value error (`sq=lastname%3Dhib%25`)

Comment: I am guessing it is not supported. That is the impression I got from a few threads in the google groups list.